# SSRS Report Builder Date Format dd.mm convert to another format

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I have the following situation from the formula at Report Builder 3.0:

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!Id.Value) = Fields!Id.Value, 
    Fields!DateStart.Value - Previous(Fields!DateFinish.Value), 
        "NA")
```

Outuput: 01:55:33:2400000

Desired Output: 01:55 H

Tried to use the FormatDateTime and others, however no value is retrieved.

Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on @HannoverFist's answer to include the "H"

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!Id.Value) = Fields!Id.Value, 
    FormatDateTime(Fields!DateStart.Value - Previous(Fields!DateFinish.Value), "hh:mm") + "H", "NA")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you are using **N/A** for some of the fields which is causing your date type to be converted to text.

If you want to keep the N/A, I would try formatting the Time inside the THEN part of the IIF statement. Converting/Formatting Date/Times actually changes the type to text which IS compatible with the N/A.

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!Id.Value) = Fields!Id.Value, 
    FormatDateTime(Fields!DateStart.Value - Previous(Fields!DateFinish.Value), "hh:mm"), 
        "NA")
```

I'm not sure what the **H** is for. :(

> Desired Output: 01:55 **H**

Comment: The "H" stands for hour, e.g.: 1 h and 55 minutes (01:55)

Comment: @EduardoMoura - so was this the issue? B's answer adding the `+ "H"` will work - though you'd want a space before the H.

Comment: Thanks HannoverFist and B.Serbele. The "H" is just to express the time length, in hours. The main issue is about the format, e.g.  01:55:33:2400000. I just want the short format 01:55.